# onNavigationStateChange is not working with my WebView URL which in Angular

Tags: react-native

It only gives the URL of the first-time (main-URL) loading wherever I click or want to navigate on any other pages, which should be different.For the SPA

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  ref={c => this._webview = c}
  source={{ uri: this.props.url }}
  dataDetectorTypes={'all'}
  onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
  onLoadStart={this._webLoadStart.bind(this)}
  onLoadEnd={this._webLoadEnd.bind(this)}
  onError={this._webLoadError.bind(this)}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPA applications don't trigger a onLoad event, so the navigationState only captures the first loaded url. You need to inject a custom javascript in your WebView that notifies the React Native app of the url change.

I would suggest the following:

If the angular app is controlled by you, then have it send a message using window.postMesssage every time the url changes.

something like this:

```
// create the function to notify React in your angular app
window.notifyReact = function(data, type){
   if(window && window.postMessage) {
     window.postMessage({data:data, type:type});
   }
}

// use the function on every route change in your angular app
notifyReact({newUrl: "https://somenewurl/with-new-params"}, "URL_CHANGE")
```

then in your react native app, listen for messages in your WebView:

```
<WebView 
    ...yourOtherProps
    onMessage={e => {
      const data = e && e.nativeEvent.data ? e.nativeEvent.data.data : null;

       //print the data coming from the angular app to the console, data.newUrl should have the new url
      console.log("data from angular app:", data);
      }
    }
/>
```

If the angular app is not controlled by you, then your best bet is to follow a similar approach with the above code by injecting a javascript when the WebView loads inside your react native app and have it intercept the url/hash changes or changes coming from window.history.pushState/popState.

Good luck!