# How to get url change event for SPA in react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am using `react-native-webview` for showing the web-view. When i change any page(non SPA) event is triggering. But when i change url in SPA application `onNavigationStateChange` event is not triggering. Is there any possibility to trigger the event in SPA

```
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

<WebView
  source={{uri: 'https://www.flipkart.com/'}}
  bounces={true}
  startInLoadingState
  scalesPageToFit
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationStateChange}
  onLoadStart={() => {
    console.log('LOAD START ');
  }}
  onLoadEnd={() => {
    console.log('LOAD END');
  }}
  onError={(err) => {
    console.log('ERROR ');
    console.log(err);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476080/onnavigationstatechange-is-not-working-with-my-webview-url-which-in-angular